# Separate dll from other output files in c++ projects

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I have a few dll projects in a solution (some depending on each other)

```
Project1 -> Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies -> Project2.lib
Project1 -> Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories -> $(OutDir)
```

All is working fine.

Projects are Win7Debug Win32, Win7Debug x64..... and a Win32 project with only Debug and Release configurations.

I would like to have all dll's for Win32 placed in one folder and the x64 ones in another folder. So I added the x64 configuration for the Win32 project, and changed

```
Project1 -> Properties -> Linker -> General -> Output File -> $(SolutionDir)/i386/$(TargetName)/$(TargetExt)
```

(for Win32 - similar change for x64)

all seemed fine - and I only received dlls in the i386 folder... until I had to rebuild and got

```
Warning 23  warning MSB8012: 
TargetPath(C:\Path\Win7Debug\Project1.dll) does not match the Linker's OutputFile 
property value (C:\Path\i386\Project1.dll). This may cause your project to build 
incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and 
$(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
```

This seems serious... and I don't want to have problems with missing dependencies (though everything seems to be working fine - and not just on my machine)

I changed

```
 Project1 -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General -> OutputDirectory -> $(SolutionDir)/i386
```

(to match the linker output) but now of course I get lib and exp files in the same folder as the dll's.

Other than using post build script, is there a way to separate the output files ?

Should I just leave the settings how I had them and disregard the warning above ?

**Note**: I am not trying to separate the Platform/configuration output files... That is done automagically using the default output directory.

What I need is, for each platform, to place only DLL files in one folder away from anything else. Redirecting Linker output (and leaving project output to standard) accomplishes that - I just am not sure if it is correct. Logically I should not have any build problems since I am giving linker all the info it needs...

Comment: I accepted the answer below since - while there don't seem to be any side effects to separating the lib from dll - it seemed  better to use the defaults provided by Visual Studio, with dependencies clearly next to the needy dlls. And make downstream application filter the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach is to leave **all** these properties unchanged (inherit from parent). In this case linker will create DLL and LIB in `$(Output)` directory, which by default is `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)`.
You just specify the name for x64 configuration, and all output files will be separated automatically.

The standard (and the easest) way to link import library is to add reference to corresponding project in `Common Properties / References` page. Nothing else is required.

If, for any reason, it is impossible, add `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)` to `Configuration Properties / VC++ Directories / Library Directories` and add library to be linked to `Linker / Additional Dependencies`. If there are many projects in your solution, you may create Property Sheet for the solution and specify `Library Directories` only once.

Comment: thank you, I have no problem linking libraries. I can link either as I described, or by adding the dependencies as references. What I am trying to do is place ONLY DLL files into specific folders (renaming project configurations is a nice idea, thank you), without the lib files.

Comment: Are you sure, you really need this? It will require additional efforts.

Comment: Anyway, I would advice to create a property sheet for solution and specify common setting in it, not overriding them in each project.

Comment: Very good point about making a common property sheet... and yes I really need this - my needs are dictated by other peoples' desires. As scary as that warning is though, so far it seems I can leave the projects with different output directories for dll and lib, with no adverse efects